# Slider labels do not correspond to the title

Tags: python, python-xarray, holoviews, geoviews

I have this xarray dataset defined as *ds*:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (bnds: 2, lag: 61, plev: 63)
Coordinates:
   * plev       (plev) float64 1e+03 925.0 850.0 800.0 780.0 750.0 700.0 ...
   * lag        (lag) int64 -30 -29 -28 -27 -26 -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -19 ...
   * bnds       (bnds) int64 0 1
Data variables:
   time_bnds  (lag, plev, bnds) float64 -3.468e+04 -3.468e+04 -3.468e+04 ...
   lat_bnds   (lag, plev, bnds) float64 -48.24 -51.95 -48.24 -51.95 -48.24 ...
   lon_bnds   (lag, plev, bnds) float64 -318.8 -322.5 -318.7 -322.5 -318.7 ...
   plev_bnds  (lag, plev, bnds) float64 -1e+05 -9.25e+04 -9.25e+04 -8.5e+04 ...
   accelogw   (lag, plev) float64 -0.001869 0.05221 0.04774 0.02534 0.02233 ...
```

where the plev coordinate is decrasing (pressure level) from 1000 to 0.0007 hPa.

I define geoviews dataset like this:

```
 import geoviews as gv
 kdims = ['plev', 'lag'] 
 vdims = ['accelogw']
 dataset = gv.Dataset(ds, kdims=kdims, vdims = vdims)
```

I create the holoviews Curve object in this way:

```
%%opts Curve [xrotation=25] NdOverlay [fig_size=300 aspect=1.2]
dataset.to(hv.Curve, 'lag')
```

resulting in frames beginning with this one:
[image]

As you can see the slider label shows the pressure level equal to 0.0007 hPa in contrary to the title showing the pressure level equal to 1000 hPa. Is it a bug or default behavior of holoviews/geoviews for dimensions?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: I have holoviews on v1.6.2, geoviews on v1.1.0 and xarray on v0.8.2.

Comment: Could you report what version you're on? I think this may have been fixed in master.

Comment: I have `holoviews` on v1.6.2, `geoviews` on v1.1.0 and `xarray` on v0.8.2.

Comment: This has been fixed in master, we're working hard to get 1.7 out as soon as possible, in the meantime you get a dev version using ``conda install -c ioam/label/dev holoviews`` or ``pip install https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/archive/v1.7dev4.tar.gz``. If you run into more problems you can also join us on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/ioam/holoviews).

Comment: Thanks @philippjfr. However, I was not able to install this properly via `pip` or `conda` on Windows 7 or Ubuntu (both 64-bit). I am still getting holoviews v1.6.2 in my `pip list`.